# virtmanager: install via debian netinstall, reboot find not boot device, recovery mode can access

Tags: ssh, shorewall

I used the virtmanager to create a virtual machine. The install medium is the debian netinstaller (Version 10, buster). Installation works without problems. Rebooting fails: no boot device found Starting the recovery mode from the netinstaller image: All resources are available, the chroot instance works fine.

```
# I used the recovery mode to reinstall grub:
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
```

I expected to see the grub dialog while booting. I found the message "no boot device found"

Comment: It seems to be a problem of debian netinstall: Using mint as live cd, installing mint and booting is possible.

Comment: Workaround: I created a boot partition, installed mint with this boot partition, then debian from the netinstall image with the same boot directory. Then the boot works.